# how to insert a word and place the letters in different index in 2d array

Tags: c++

```
insert element: hello
```

for example i input the word hello, it should place the letters in each succeeding index. i tried string but it seems it compressed to a single index and gives me unexpected behavior if i tried to add more.

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0 1  2  3  4  5  a  b  c  d  e
1 f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  s
2 h  e  l  l  o
==========================================
```

here is my poorly attempted code:

```
#include<iostream>

std::string myarray[3][10] = {{"1","2","3","4","5","a","b","c","d","e"},
                            {"f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","s",}, 
                            {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ",}};

void displaygrid();

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int col = 0;
    char insert; //i tried strings but it was out of order

        displaygrid();
        cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
        cout<<"insert element: ";
        cin>>insert;
        myarray[2][col] = insert;
        cout<<"Insert Successful!" <<endl;
        col++;
        displaygrid();
}


void displaygrid(){

    cout<<endl;
    for(int z = 0; z<10; z++){
        cout<<"  "<<z;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
    cout<<x;
        for(int y = 0; y<10; y++){
            cout<<" " <<myarray[x][y] <<" ";
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can index into a `std::string` with `[]` so you only really need an array of `std::string`. But you really should be using `std::array/std::vector` instead of c-style arrays.

Comment: thank you for replying. im not allowed to use vectors and do you have a simplified/beginner example?

Comment: If you have a `std::string str = "hello"` then `str[1] == 'e'`. If you have `std::string arr[3] = {"hello", "test", "ing"};` then `arr[1][2] == 's'`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super) mentioned, you can do this with strings. Here is some code that should get you started.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){
  std::string grid;

  //get insert element
  std::cout << "Insert Element: ";
  std::cin >> grid;

  //print the grid using rowLength for number of elements along x
  const int rowLength = 10;
  int run = 0;
  for(auto x : grid)
  {
    std::cout << x << " | ";
    run++;

    if(run >= rowLength)
    {
      std::cout << std::endl;
      run = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i see, what does auto x do? and only 1 loop for 2d array?

Comment: auto will deduce the correct type of x in the range based for loop, but you can ignore that for now and use `char & x : grid` instead. I've used a 1D array that adds a newline when the end of a row is reached (defined by `rowLength`). If you know the grid size you can use some simple math to read/write into a 1D array given [row, col].